# How many people died in the USA on average per day including up to 2019?

Tags: epidemiology, death

On average, how many people die every day in the USA?

The statistics for 2019 and before.

Comment: Did you already run a Google search on this topic?

Comment: @Thomas If we provide useful answers here, then one day when people Google this topic, they'll be able to learn from our answers. We can collate sources, add commentary and clarifications from the experts here that would take days of Googling to pull together.

Comment: @Thomas by searching on Google I can only find virus statistics

Answer (score 3):

In 2018, approximately 7779 people died per day in the US as per the [CDC National Vital Statistics System](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/mortality.htm?CDC_AA_refVal=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cdc.gov%2Fnchs%2Fnvss%2Fdeaths.htm).